# How to add back button when we have three UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios6

I am learning Navigation controller from [this link](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/).

I have created it as per this link. However, now what I want is add one more `UIViewController` before first where I will have a button as `My Recipe Book`. When I click on this button, I will see the first screen that is there in the example. When I see the second screen (where I will have a list of items (screen 1 in example)), the Navigation bar should have a back button like what I have in above the example in the second screen.

Any idea how to get this done?

I tried adding new `UIViewController` and adding navigation controller and connecting this `UIViewController` to first `UIViewController` in example with `MODAL`.

It works, however I don't see back button.

Comment: Could you show me your storyboard?

Comment: @Dudi : Check link I have provided. Its same I have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer... Yes I made it finally...

I added new `UIViewController` and linked this new `UIViewController` to Navigation controller that is already present.

Earlier :

```
Navigation Controller >> UIViewController 1 >> UIViewController 2
```

What I was trying, which was not working

```
Navigation Controller >> New UIViewController >> Navigation Controller >> UIViewController 1 >> UIViewController 2
```

**Below is what is working**

```
Navigation Controller >> New UIViewController >> UIViewController 1 >> UIViewController 2
```

Answer (score 0):

set title to each view controller's viewDidLoad method using....

```
    [self setTitle:@"myViewController"];
```

and if navigation bar is hidden then make it visible using ......

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```